# Android Data binding: @Binable vs Observablefield performance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Which gives more performance here?

`@Bindable` uses: `notifyPropertyChanged(fieldName)` where 
`Observablefield` uses `notifyChange()` in set method which notifies everything in the file.

```
private class User extends BaseObservable {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   @Bindable
   public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
   }
   @Bindable
   public String getLastName() {
       return this.lastName;
   }
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
   }
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName);
   }
}
```

vs

```
private class User {
   public final ObservableField<String> firstName =
       new ObservableField<>();
   public final ObservableField<String> lastName =
       new ObservableField<>();

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       firstName.set(firstName)
   }
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       lastName.set(lastName)
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter, they both are efficient.

I was under the impression that when we call `Observablefield .set(newValue)` method it triggers `notifyChange()` which updates all fields of `User` class but that's incorrect. It only updates that field only as `notifyChange()` belongs to that `Observablefield` object, not a `User` object.